# Touch gesture - Drag makes paint(Graphics g) behaviour odd

Tags: codenameone

I am overwritting the default paint method, and everything is working fine. I have a running game in CodenameOne (plays smooth, everything works), but the downside is: I had to use buttons for player movement. I would like to use "swipe" gestures, which is in itself a relatively simple implementation. However, when I swipe on the screen, what is painted gets removed, so I am left with just the background (for a split second, the paint continues when releasing the drag).

Any idea on how to fix this issue - without overriding the behaviour of touch gestures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't override `paint` in `Form`, it has some special cases. The best workaround is to create a component and place it in a `BorderLayout.CENTER` in the `Form`.

Comment: How would be the proper way to draw images (such as a game)? In overriding the paint, I actually call the super() first. Interesting to note is that the game actually works and has been tested under Lumia520, a relatively low end device, but I'm happy to rewrite it properly :)

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. Just override the paint in the component within the form instead of the paint in the form itself.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that was to the drag issue. I will do it that way thwn, thanks Shai! :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution I have at the moment is the following. Everything still seems to work!

```
public void pointerDragged(int x, int y)
{
    System.out.println("This shouldn't do anything");
}

public void pointerDragged(int[] x, int[] y) 
{
    System.out.println("This shouldn't do anything either");
}
```